# How to Loop through serialized json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, foreach, json-deserialization

`Res={"result":["123","563"]}`

This is the similar json file i have. I have to loop through it and assign each value as ids.
I am trying as

```
Obj = JsonConvert.DeseraializeObject<classname>(Res);
Foreach(string id in Obj)
{Function();}
```

I'm getting error as *class doesn't have extension for getenumerator*

Edit:
I did this

```
List<classname> objlist = jsonconvert.deserializeObject<list<classname>>(res); 
foreach (string id in objlist)
{function();}
```

getting an error for *foreach loop as cannot convert classname to string*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please bear in mind that C# is a case-sensitive language. So, please try to provide valid C# code, which can be compiled.

Answer (score 1):

In JSON file you have string array with key "results". It can be modelled like this:

```
public class Result
{
    public List<string> results { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize and then loop through it in the next way:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(Res);
    foreach (var id in data.results)
    {
      // Assignment logic
    }
```

Comment: This code will crash with `NullReferenceException`. The sample json contains a field called `result`. Your `Result` class defines a property (`Results`) which is not present in the json, that's why it will be null. The app will fail when it reaches foreach. Please fix your proposed solution.

Comment: Please explain your code (even explanatory code comments are helpful).

Answer (score 0):

Your object should have property List or List and you will iterate throw it, not in Obj.

Answer (score 0):

Your Json structure looks something like this in c#

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Result
{ 
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    List<string> Res { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialze:

```
Result r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(jsonString);
```

Briefly explained: Your json has a property called "result", this property is a "list" of type "string" `List<string>.`